# What am I doing wrong? Trying to join a row_id with the same row_id in a subquery to derive a count

Tags: sql, oracle

So i am trying to get a count of the number of files a user is linked to. However, the par_row_ids (original_table identifiers) are not joining for some odd reason What I have is as follows:

```
SELECT file_count.par_row_id,
       original_table.par_row_id,
       file_count.count
FROM   original_table original_table
       left outer join (SELECT original_table.par_row_id,
                               Count(*) AS count
                        FROM   original_table original_table
                        WHERE  type_code = 'file'
                        GROUP  BY original_table.par_row_id) file_count
                    ON original_table.par_row_id = file_count.par_row_id;
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: Oracle is what i'm using. sorry i added a suggest tag without looking

Comment: What does Oracle say? Any error? Or does it just return *nothing*? Does inline view (your FILE_COUNT) return anything? Possibly, post a test case so that we could have a look.

Comment: it returns null for everything. no syntax errors however

Comment: why do you use `original_table` to alias `original_table`, use `o` as an example. By the way, are you have at least one row with `not null par_row_id` column populated and having value of `type_code` as `file`(all in small letters, case-sensitivity may cause the typo also).

Comment: i'll change the alias names. i got it to work, i needed  right join instead of a left. im not sure why

Comment: A right outer join is just a left outer join written backwards to confuse everyone. You can always achieve the same thing by switching the two tables around and keeping it a regular left join.

Answer (score 1):

Your aliasing is not the most intuitive but the query should return some join results. I am wondering if you'd rather do the following:

```
select ot.par_row_id,
       nvl(x.c,0) as cnt
from original_table ot
left outer join (
                  select par_row_id,
                         count(*) as c
                  from original_table
                  where type_code = 'file'
                  group by par_row_id
                ) x
on ot.par_row_id = x.par_row_id;
```

Comment: i stil return all null values for both par_row_ids for some odd reason

Comment: You have to post your schema and if possible some data - I was merely refining the exact SQL you posted.

Comment: turns out doing a right outer join instead of a left did the trick (for some odd reason)